# How to Implement Swipe Gesture in Down Direction for UITableView?

Tags: iphone, tableview, multi-touch, swipe

I tried the following code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *showBar = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureShowBar:)];
showBar.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
showBar.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.tableview addGestureRecognizer:showBar];
```

with no luck! The tableview tends to scroll when I swipe is performed using two fingers. So, I tried disabling multi-touch on tableview and let the superview handle the gesture:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *showBar = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureShowBar:)];
showBar.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
showBar.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:showBar];
```

Again, it doesn't work! I really wonder why a tableview will respond to two finger swipe although multi-touch is not enabled!

Comment: There is a more tedious way of achieving this, a way used before the days of UIGestureRecognizer. Subclassing UITableView and overriding its UIResponder methods. I tried using a swip gesture recognizer as you did but it seems that the tableView still receives higher priority, even after implementing the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch. Maybe I didn't play long and hard enough, so maybe give it a try?

Comment: Batter u add the swipe gesture to cell no entire table view and also allocate above swipe gesture methods in the cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0):

this link describe how to implement pinch gesture in a table row u can adjust swipe gesture instead of it

check out the tableviewcontroller class where handle pinch method is there
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139

Good luck

Comment: yes, I saw that already, but it's not the same. If you tried to swipe the tableview in down direction, it scrolls downward and hence blocks any gesture.

Comment: you just need to take custom cell and in the custom class you have to apply swipe event where you need to take one view for the entire cell and apply swipe gesture to that particular view it will definitely work